# Uploading image from Node JS on Cloudinary error: "Must_supply_cloud_name", but Cloud_name is given correctly in the config

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images on Cloudinary from Node JS, but it fails with the error "Must supply cloud_name", I have the cloudinary config parameters coming from the dotenv file, and I've confirmed that these parameters are correctly passing to the file where I make the Cloudinary call, I have tried to send a sample image to test if the problem is my data but the same error is given, here is the code where the problem is :

```
const Features = require("../utils/Features");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;


cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME, 
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
  secure: true
});
console.log(cloudinary.config());

exports.createProduct = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  let images = [];
  if (typeof req.body.images === "string") {
    images.push(req.body.images);
  } else {
    images = req.body.images;
  }
  
  const imagesLinks = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    try{
      cloudinary.uploader.upload("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Olympic_flag.jpg",
      { public_id: "olympic_flag" }, 
      function(error, result) {console.log(result); });
      const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(images[i], {
        upload_preset: "products",
      });

      imagesLinks.push({
        public_id: result.public_id,
        url: result.secure_url,
      });
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({err: "Error"});
    }
  }

  req.body.images = imagesLinks;
  req.body.user = req.user.id;

  const product = await Product.create(req.body);

  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    product,
  });
});
```

This is my dotenv file :
`DB_URL = "database_url" PORT = 4000 JWT_SECRET_KEY=secret JWT_EXPIRES="120m" COOKIE_EXPIRE="7200" CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME="cloud_name" CLOUDINARY_API_KEY="api_key" CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET="secret" CLOUDINARY_URL="cloudinary://key:secret@cloud_name"`
The `console.log(cloudinary.config());` gives me the fields correctly, and the `require('dotenv').config` is used in my index.js .
Can someone help me identify the cause of the problem and fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting must supply cloud name error then it means your dotenv configuration has not been set properly.

How exactly are you setting the credentials in your dotenv file? Send us a copy with redacted values if possible.

If you set the actual values in the config, does it work? i.e.

```
cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: random, 
  api_key: 8383773,
  api_secret: df9df89dfdhfdg,
  secure: true
});
```

You can also simply set the CLOUDINARY_URL in your .env file per https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#setting_the_cloudinary_url_environment_variable and use `require('dotenv').config();` to pull the credentials. Here is a sample project using this method: https://github.com/cloudinary-training/cld-fundamentals-for-developers